# Changing the Color of links/text in HTML with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm setting up a web application via ASP.NET, and I want my links to change a specific color for a specific amount of time once they've been used. How might I go about doing this?

I haven't tested any of this out yet. I don't know exactly where to begin.

So say on my web application I have a link on my home page. It's default color is black. I want to be able to click on the link, have it bring me to the corresponding linked page. This linked page allows me to edit fields, add comments, etc. I want any edits/comments to trigger a specific change, such that when I go back to my homepage, the link is a different color, say green.

think of the color change as a type of "read" feature for emails. If I have multiple links, I want to know which ones I have visited and made changed to. this is different than the hyperlink color change where it turns a different color once clicked, since this isn't a permanent change, and the link could return to the default color if the page has been refreshed.

Any ideas?

Edit1: The infrastructure for this problem was passed onto me by someone else, and it would be hard to move this to another language type.

Edit2: I currently have the following code pertaining to this one link:

```
<body>"Identification number: <a href="http://google.com/" link="black alink="green" vlink = "green" target = "_blank">@Model.id</a></body>
```

where "@Model.id" is declared in the following c# code

```
namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public string time { get; set; }
        public int id = 12345;
        public void OnGet()
        {
            time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd probably have a much easier time doing this with Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Show us a minimal code example of your problem.